# NodeJS / RequireJS: models loading late

Tags: node.js, requirejs, sequelize.js

I'm working on a refactor of my application.  I'm using require.js at the top of a service class to get my sequelize models -- I have about 15 models.

For some reason, the models are an empty object unless I require them further down in my flow (moving the `require` statement inside a function call works, for example).

So for example, when the `require` is at the top, a statement like `models.Foo.findOne()` throws `Cannot read property Foo of undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out I had a circular dependency -- essentially a model ended up dependent on a file that required models.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime I use similar code to avoid this problem:

```
(() => models.Foo)().findOne()
```

or

```
(() => Bar.sequelize.models.Foo)().findOne()
```